# SmartGit: Change submodule URL

Tags: url, git-submodules, smartgit

I'm using SmartGit to handle my Git repos.
Some of these repos have submodules and if I want to change their URLs for now I open a Git shell and I change the URLs in .gitmodules using a text editor.

How can I change those URLs within SmartGit ?

thanks.

Comment: When changing URLs in .gitmodules, this won't affect your current repository, but only fresh clones (once committed and pushed). Is this actually what you intend? If so, there is no way to do that from SmartGit.

Comment: @mstrap: Yes I want to change the submodule's URL, commit it and push it to the server so my co-workers can pull the repo and get it correctly setup with the new submodule's URL.